# Can I use both of app A & B that A checks that B not installed?

Tags: android, installed-applications

I had to use two apps on my android mobile that I named A & B.
A check that B not installed in mobile.
Can I do this?
I used app cloner, APK Editor, APK manager and some other apps to rename app name but it doesn't work.

Comment: What do mean by this ? Is this question even related to programming ?

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean appInstalledOrNot(String uri) {
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        try {
            pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
            return true;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        }

        return false;`
    }
```

you can call this method where you want to check if application is installed or not 
Hope this helps

Answer (score -2):

I use the following approach.

```
boolean isAppInstalled = appInstalledOrNot("com.check.application");  

    if(isAppInstalled) {
        //This intent will help you to launch if the package is already installed
        Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager()
            .getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.check.application");
        startActivity(LaunchIntent);

        Log.i("Application is already installed.");       
    } else {
        // Do whatever we want to do if application not installed
        // For example, Redirect to play store

        Log.i("Application is not currently installed.");
    }
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score -2):

yes，yes, because there is a plugin or code that can directly help you check if the  App is already in place.

boolean isAppInstalled = appInstalledOrNot("com.check.application");

```
if(isAppInstalled) {
    //This intent will help you to launch if the package is already installed
    Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager()
        .getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.check.application");
    startActivity(LaunchIntent);

    Log.i("Application is already installed.");       
} else {
    // Do whatever we want to do if application not installed
    // For example, Redirect to play store

    Log.i("Application is not currently installed.");
}
```

Comment: there is a plugin ? Seriously ??

Comment: no no no the plugin will need  you to find it